# How to specify index of specific elements in every sublist of nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function

i have several nested lists, which are all permutations of each other within sublists:

```
x = [
['a', [['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]]],
['a', [['b', [['e', 'd']], 'c']]],
[[['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]], 'a'],
['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]], 
['a', [['b', [['d', 'e']], 'c']]]
]
```

I want to select only those, which comply with this requirement: if sublists contains element 'd' or 'b' in it, it must have index 0 in that sublist.
So among lists in x only

```
['a', [['b', [['d', 'e']], 'c']]]
```

must be selected, because 'd' has index 0 in its sublist and at the same time 'b' has index 0 in its sublist.
I tried this function:

```
def limitation(root, nested):
    result = []
    for i in nested:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            return limitation(root, i)
        else:
            if (i in ['d', 'b']  and nested.index(i) == 0):
                return root
for i in x:
    print(limitation(i, i))
```

But the output was this:

```
['a', [['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]]]
['a', [['b', [['e', 'd']], 'c']]]
[[['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]], 'a']
['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]]
['a', [['b', [['d', 'e']], 'c']]]
```

So it didn't consider that both 'd' and 'b' must have index 0 in there sublists. Could you please help me to fix it?

Comment: `['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]], ` why this is not valid ?

Comment: because in sublist [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']] 'b' hasn't index 0, it has index 2. so both 'd' and 'b' must have indexes 0. that's why this one ['a', [['b', [['d', 'e']], 'c']]] is the only right variant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a `sub-list` contains `'b' or 'd'` that element must be in the **first index**  `[0]`:

```
x = [
['a', [['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]]],
['a', [['b', [['e', 'd']], 'c']]],
[[['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]], 'a'],
['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]],
['a', [['b', [['d', 'e']], 'c']]]
]


def limitation(nested):
    for index, subelement in enumerate(nested):
        if isinstance(subelement, list):
            if not limitation(subelement):
                return False
        else:
            if subelement in ['d', 'b'] and not index:
                return False
    return True


for element in x:
    if limitation(element):
        print(element)  # ['a', [['b', [['d', 'e']], 'c']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
x = [
['a', [['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]]],
['a', [['b', [['e', 'd']], 'c']]],
[[['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]], 'a'],
['a', [[[['d', 'e']], 'c', 'b']]], 
['a', [['b', [['d', 'e']], 'c']]]
]

def is_valid(sub, seen=0):
    if sub[0] in ('b', 'd'):
        if seen == 1:
            # we found 'b' and 'd' at the right positions
            return True
        else:
            # we found the first one of them
            seen = 1

    elif any(item in sub for item in ('b', 'd')):
        # this sublist has 'b' or 'd' in other than first position
        return False

    # still undecided, we check the sublists recursively
    for item in sub:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            return is_valid(item, seen)

[s for s in x if is_valid(s)]
# [['a', [['b', [['d', 'e']], 'c']]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you stop looking for more lists within the lists one you have found either a single 'b' or a single 'd'. For example, call the function as:

```
limitation(x[0], x[0])
```

First it will check if the 'a' in ['a', [['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]]] is a list -> it is not a list, so it goes on to check if it is 'b' or 'd' -> it is not, so the loop goes to the next item. Now it will check if [['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]] is a list -> it is, so it calls the function again with ['b', 'c', [['e', 'd']]]. Now it will check if 'b' is a list -> it is not, so now it checks if it is 'b' or 'd'- which it is, and so the root is returned. It never gets on to checking for remaining lists- including, in this case, one which contains 'd' not in a zero position. Hopefully that makes sense.